# From CLIB to DLIB: size_t is undefined

Tags: c, c99, iar, texas-instruments

I'm trying to link DLIB to a (CLIB) project that I'm working on. It builds fine when linked to CLIB, but I get the following error when linked to DLIB:

Error[Pe020]: identifier "size_t" is undefined C:\Texas Instruments\BLE-CC254x-1.4.1.43908a\Projects\ble\Profiles\DevInfo\devinfoservice.c 137

Is `size_t` invalid in DLIB? The DLIB I'm using is IAR's "Normal DLIB" as selected below.

[image]

Is there any way to use the `size_t` type? I believe TI uses CLIB in their projects, but I wonder if there's a quick way to make DLIB to play ball.

Thanks

Comment: This might sound silly, but have you actually included `stddef.h`, where `size_t` is defined?

Comment: Yes, I have included it.

Answer (score 0):

user694733 might be right.
did you include the right header?
e.g

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```